# A recipe that's going places

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

What is this a recipe for?

> Carefully slice the forgiveness into 6 even pieces
>   Apply a generous amount of Angola extract
>   Optionally sprinkle a small amount of digits
>   Whisk with a stick
>   Serves one

Hint 1:

> Angola extract = extract the Angola

Hint 2:

> The digits are actually optional.

Hint 3:

> Whisk with a stick = mix the characters and they go with a stick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recipe is for

> Driving (a car with an automatic transmission), which also fits the "going places" hint in the title.

Slicing forgiveness into six pieces:

> p-a-r-d-o-n

Extracting Angola:

> Angola's TLD is .ao, removing a and o leaves p-r-d-n

Whisk with a stick:

> Mix the letters to get P-R-N-D for Park, Reverse, Neutral and Drive, which go along a gear stick

Optional digits:

> Some gearboxes provide a mode for limiting the transmission to only some of the lowest gears, those options are marked with small digits.

Serves one

> The driver is (hopefully) the only person to operate the gear stick.

Comment: Some cars also have something like PRND where D has a part to the side (with digits) which allows you to choose the gear.

Comment: Bravo on the answer and bounty :)

Comment: As well as TLD: ISO code and NATO country code

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> Saresa or aratalis fruit

Because:

> I didn't get the part with 6 pieces, so I went forward.
>  If you add Angola extract from forgiveness you'll get (get rid of same letteres and add the rest): 
>  FRIVEESSALA 
>  Digits are optional, so we get rid of them too. From frivessala you can get FIVE. We'll get rid of it and receive RESSALA.
>  Now we mix with a stick and l in ressala looks like a stick. We mix it, letters follow the the stick and get SARESAL. Then we take the stick out, as we don't want to eat it and we get SARESA. Also, the fruit is small, perfect for serving one.

Comment: Good answer but not correct. Also, the 6 is important.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a partial answer, I guess, it is a sort of

> ... CUISINE

As,

> Forgiveness = E X C U S E

And

> Then take suitable letter combinations from **Angola** and **digits** like
>  N,__, __, __, __ (from Angola) and  I, I (from digits) and rearrange them

to get

> .... CUISINE

Here is my 2nd answer:

It could be a

> Padŕon,

Which is a kind of dish that can serve one and served on /with a stick.

Here is a reference (refer item #16)

> https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.brit.co/appetizers-on-sticks/amp/&ved=0ahUKEwim-b6grczWAhXDQI8KHW4EDRwQFggxMAE&usg=AOvVaw0T3yajb4r386-mSEsrEQ-x&ampcf=1

And the explanation is

> Forgiveness is P A R D O N and the dish name can be arrived at by rearranging the letters and adding other stuff such as eggs, and its  link to Angola to be explored.

Comment: how do you get 'EXCUSE' from 'forgiveness'? those don't seem related to me.

Comment: Well, to excuse someone is to forgive them for something.

Comment: Oh I forgot excuse could be a verb.

Comment: Good answer but not correct.

Comment: You got the forgiveness word right in your second answer. The answer has nothing to do with food.

Comment: The correct answer has been given now. But props for getting the forgiveness word.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> Pride

because:

Slice the forgiveness into 6 even pieces

> A six letter synonym for forgiveness is "pardon." Slicing this into six pieces gives "P-A-R-D-O-N."

Apply a generous amount of Angola Extract:

> Remove letters in "Angola" from the letters in "P-A-R-D-O-N" to get "prd."

Optionally sprinkle a small amount of digits

> digits = fingers, and we happen to have five of those on one hand. The fifth letter of the alphabet is "E" which added to the end gives us "prde."

Whisk with a stick

> Throw an "I" in there because it looks like a stick and we get "pride."

Serves one

> Pride is good for no one but yourself in most cases. If you are too prideful for example, you may hurt others while boosting your own ego.

Comment: Check the hints - it breaks one of your steps.